# Handler function when group row is selected/clicked in a jqGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Is an event handler triggered when a group header row is clicked?  I am aware of:

```
onClickGroup: function(hid) {
    /* Fired when group header icon is toggled */
}
```

but I need to also emulate the same behavior when a row containing group is clicked. I could emulate the toggle using:

```
jQuery('#GridID').jqGrid('groupingToggle', 'QCStatusghead_0_3');
```

Comment: what version of jqGrid you use? which fork of jqGrid you use? ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <=4.7)

Comment: @Oleg I am using `4.6.0`

Comment: In the case you can remove `$groupHeader` parameter (see my answer) because it will be used in free jqGrid starting with 4.10.0 for better performance, but in general the usage of the parameter makes no disadvantages in jqGrid 4.6.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple code

```
$grid.click(function (e) {
    var $groupHeader = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgroup");
    if ($groupHeader.length > 0) {
        $(this).jqGrid("groupingToggle", $groupHeader.attr("id"), $groupHeader);
    }
});
```

where `$grid` is the grid (`$("#gridId")`).

See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/tougleOnClickOnGroupRow.htm).